# Redirect to login if the other page is idle for 1 minutes c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-timeout

I want that if user is not accessing site for 1 minutes(means browser is idle for 1 min) , after 1 min. when user clicks on any link, his session should be expired and he has to provide login credentials again.

Login Page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default3Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["id"] = TextBox1.Text;
        //Session["pass"] = TextBox2.Text;
        Response.Redirect("Default3Logout.aspx");
        Session.RemoveAll();

    }
}
```

Home page :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default3Logout : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label2.Text = Session["id"].ToString();

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Session.Remove("id"); you wana remove one by one use this.
        Session.RemoveAll();
        Response.Redirect("Default3Login.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2008/11/detecting-session-timeout-and-redirect.html

Comment: You should be using `Forms Authentication` with timeout value of `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to maintain session for users. You can refer to this [Link for session management.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/416137/Understanding-Session-Management-Techniques-in-ASP)

Answer (score 1):

Form Authentication is an option for you. But if you are not using that(or even if you are using) it can be easily done by javascript.

You can redirect your user to Logout-page or call method to log him out where you are kicking him out of session.

And another benifit is that you can smoothly reset tour timer when user interact with pages.(check out javascript `events`). This is one of the possible directions for doing this.

Here is some relative code:

```
//javascript function
function logout()
{
    //hit the logout page or method using jQuery/xmlhttp
    $.post("logout.aspx?action=logout",{},function(data){
    location.href="logout.aspx";
});
}
```

In code behind file contain following code for peform logout operation

```
//under pageload of logout.aspx
if(request.Querystring["action"]!=null)
{
  response.clear();
  Session.abondon();
  response.write("Success");
  response.End();
}
```

Try & Cheers!!